# How do I create a multiline textbox that adjusts the height automatically when the window is resized

Tags: firefox, xul

I have prefwindow with a multiline textbox. When I resize the window, its width changes but its height is constant. How do I make its height variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but:

- Maybe you need to set the *align* attribute on the prefwindow, or the contained preferences element to "stretch". Then you also need to set the flex attribute on the textbox.
- You could also try to dynamically change the "rows" attribute of the texbox.